# Error 1054 Unknown column 'company_id' in 'NEW'

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a very simple trigger that intermittently causes MySQL to thrown error 1054 "Unknown column 'company_id' in 'NEW'"

My trigger is defined as:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `retrieve_quotes` 
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON `company_tick_data_t`

    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        SET @r_code = NEW.r_code;

        SET NEW.`company_id` = 
            (
                SELECT id 
                FROM companies_t
                WHERE `r_code` = @r_code
                LIMIT 1
            );


    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

What I don't understand is that it was working fine earler, and I've checked to ensure the column company_id exists in the companies_t.

Previously, company_id was setting to NULL if there wasn't a value in the companies_t table, or obviously the corresponding company_id if the record existed. Like I say, I plain don't understand why it's not working now.

Any pointers on where this might be going wrong would be received gratefully. I've Googled and looked through other solutions, but none of them match my scenario where i'm changing a value before inserting it into the table based on the result of a select query.

Comment: does the `company_id` column exist in the `company_tick_data_t` table?

Comment: Hi

Yes, it certainly does. This is what makes this so confusing. It's intermittent too. When it doesn't work, I have to truncate the table and it starts working again. I just don't understand this. I'm running MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is ancient, but I had a similar headache with a column named **InventoryKey** in my database (after fiddling around with Stored Procedures).  The field existed, but MySql was having none of it!

```
mysql> describe Inventory;
    +-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    | Field                 | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
    +-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    | inventoryId           | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
    | inventoryKey          | char(8)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
    | inventoryBatchId      | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
    | inventoryStatusTypeId | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
    | inventoryCreationTime | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
    | inventoryBatchSerial  | int(3)        | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
    | inventoryComment      | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
    +-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    7 rows in set (0.14 sec)
```

But for some reason another column name (inventoryGuid) was referenced in the error:

```
mysql>    insert into Inventory (inventoryKey) values (LEFT(MD5(RAND()),8));
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'inventoryGuid' in 'NEW'
```

After double-checking all the field names, I concluded it was some type of corruption.  Restarting the SQL database did not remedy this.  In the end, I resorted to recreating the table as follows:

```
mysql> create table InventoryStaging like Inventory;                                                                                                                    
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.62 sec) 

mysql> insert into InventoryStaging select * from Inventory;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> drop table Inventory;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

mysql> create table Inventory like InventoryStaging;                                                                                                                    
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.80 sec)

mysql> insert into Inventory select * from InventoryStaging;                                                                                                            
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

... and then the same command was successful:

```
mysql> insert into Inventory (inventoryKey) values (LEFT(MD5(RAND()),8));                                                                                               
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

Hope this prevents a bit of frustration and hair-loss elsewhere!